# Mapping subdomain to another server

Tags: web-server, subdomain, website, mapping

I have two servers, in which one I have my domain mapped fully and in another server I have a wordpress blog installed. Now, I want to map a subdomain in the first server to the one which has wordpress installed, without any change of URL. Is this possible? I hope I am making myself clear.

Answer (score 1):

DNS is completely separate function: you could have dozens of sub-domains for example.com pointing to dozens of IP addresses (and dozens of servers behind those IP addresses).

If these servers are behind their own public, routable IP address, you simply need add an A record for subdomain.example.com to point to the public IP that routes/NATs to your Wordpress server.

If these servers are behind the same public, routable IP address (and you only have one) you're going to need to use a reverse proxy in front of those servers (and behind the firewall) to redirect requests to the appropriate server based on the domain that was requested.  If you don't use a reverse proxy, you'd have to port forward 8080 to the Wordpress server (http://subdomain.example.com:8080) and that's obviously not ideal.

Comment: you guys are awesome! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the 'A' name in the DNS records, so that the subdomain points to your other server's IP .